# My real AdMob adUnitID doesn't work but i can see test ones

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob

**EDITED:** Okay so after googling a little bit more. I found this other stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797974/admob-ads-not-displaying-ios) that says that it might even take 12 hours for the production AdMob to be activated. If that occurs, I will close this post.

I made an iOS game and I added some AdMob. Created the AdMob account, linked my game with the itunesconnect app info. So everything seemed to be working fine.
Afterwards, they give you the real adUnitID. But when I add it, it doesn't show up. Only when I use the test ones.

Why is that? am I doing something wrong ? or this is on purpose?

Here's my code:

```
var googleBannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        self.googleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        self.googleBannerView.rootViewController = self
        //for testing simple : ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
        //for testing interstitial : ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
        //for production : ca-app-pub-6797599317996282/85919XXXXX
        let request = GADRequest()
//        request.testDevices = ["d0acc1d1423027d2d259f6bb2cbb9652"]
        self.googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)

        self.googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.height - self.googleBannerView.frame.size.height,
                                                 self.googleBannerView.frame.size.width, self.googleBannerView.frame.size.height)

//        self.googleBannerView.hidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(self.googleBannerView)

    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        self.googleBannerView.hidden = false
    }

    func adView(bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        self.googleBannerView.hidden = true
    }
```

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with admob, but usually when that happened it was some misconfiguration on the adMob side (serving ads in the wrong size and whatnot)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I followed this tutorial on youtube /watch?v=xavAfvWrClk and it looks like it worked for that guy in the demo... i did everything he did :( guess i will have to keep digging.

Comment: it does take a while for the ad service to go to production mode,  I would just be patient if you didn't get the service working already.  If you already pushed your binary to the app store,  you are going to have to wait 8 days anyway for it to be updated.